# Do object literals block in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, blocking, promise

Do object literals block? I am trying to store the results of other functions in my pagination helper class and my Mocha tests fail due to timeout because the callback is not returned. If I remove `local` from all my variables (i.e. `local.count` to `count`) and I remove the `.then` holding the callback and place it in the first `.then` it suddenly works.

```
   render: (model, query, cb) =>
    self = @ 
    count = 0 
    local = {}

    count_promise = @query_count model, query

    count_promise.then (c) ->
      local.count = c 
      local.pages = self.pages(count)
      local.prev_class = self.prev_class(pages)
      local.next_class = self.next_class(pages)
      local.prev_page = self.prev_page(pages)
      local.next_page = self.next_page(pages)
    .then ->
      cb({num_pages: local.pages, current_page: self.page, prev_class: local.prev_class, next_class: local.next_class, prev_page: local.prev_page, next_page: local.next_page, results: {}})

    .fail (err) ->
      throw new Error(err)

    return
```

EDIT

I added console.log before the callback to see if anything showed up.

```
.then ->
      console.log local
      cb({num_pages: local.pages, current_page: self.page, prev_class: local.prev_class, next_class: local.next_class, prev_page: local.prev_page, next_page: local.next_page, results: {}})
```

Nothing came across.

The Mocha testing code for this particular method using Sinon and Chai Asserts:

```
describe 'PaginationHelper', ->

  describe 'Pagination Helper Initializes', ->
    it 'accepts page', ->
      assert.ok(new PaginationHelper(2))

  describe 'method testing', ->

    describe 'render method', ->
        ph = new PaginationHelper(2)
        result = {}

        before (done) ->
          ph.render BlogModel, {}, (res) ->
            result = res
            done()

        it 'returns object', ->
          assert.isObject(result)

        it 'returns object with num_pages', ->
          assert.property(result, "num_pages")

        it 'returns object with current_page', ->
          assert.property(result, 'current_page')

        it 'returns object with prev_class', ->
          assert.property(result, 'prev_class')

        it 'returns object with next_class', ->
          assert.property(result, 'next_class')

        describe 'render output testing', ->
          result = undefined

          before (done) ->
            ph = new PaginationHelper(1)
            ph.render BlogModel, {}, (res) ->
              result = res
              done()

          it 'returns a number for num_pages', ->
            assert.isNumber(result.num_pages)

          it 'returns a number for current_page', ->
            assert.isNumber(result.current_page)

          it 'returns string for prev_class', ->
            assert.isString(result.prev_class)

          it 'returns string for next_class', ->
            assert.isString(result.next_class)
```

The result output of this test:

```
Error: Command failed:   ✖ 1 of 35 tests failed:

  1) PaginationHelper method testing render method "before all" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
```

Comment: You have exception when accessing undefined value property and callback function is never executed, thus timeout in Mocha

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured that local could preserve the values from the first .then to the second .then as I will be inserting more promise functions. Why doesn't the "local" object literal in the higher scope work asynchronously like a normal function variable?

Comment: I might be wrong in the previous answer. Can you post minimum self-contained example? I suspect your second `then` is not called (can you put `console.log` before `cb`?

Comment: @AndreySidorov I posted an edit to my original post with the modified code. I did a console.log and got nothing. You may be right that the second then isn't called. I also tried sticking a "console.log local" at the end of the first .then and nothing came up either.

Comment: @JPRichardson Added per your request. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I didn't understand the chaining of thenables correctly until I delved into the [Q promises API](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) heavily. There were also stupid mistakes in variables I didn't correct. Coding while super tired is not cool. Here is how the code should look:

```
render: (model, query, cb) =>
    self = @  

    count_promise = @query_count model, query

    count_promise.fail (err) ->
      throw new Error(err)
    .then (c) ->
      defer = Q.defer()
      local = {}
      local.count = c 
      local.pages = self.pages(local.count)
      local.prev_class = self.prev_class(local.pages)
      local.next_class = self.next_class(local.pages)
      local.prev_page = self.prev_page(local.pages)
      local.next_page = self.next_page(local.pages)
      defer.resolve(local)
      return defer.promise
    .then (local) ->
      cb({num_pages: local.pages, current_page: self.page, prev_class: local.prev_class, next_class: local.next_class, prev_page: local.prev_page, next_page: local.next_page, results: {}})
    return
```